# How can I migrate the data from one table to other efficiently without fail in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables suppose t1 and t2.

```
T1 has columns - c1, c2, c3, c4, c5
T2 has columns - ac1, ac2, ac3, ac4
```

I have to migrate the values of c1 of t1 into ac4 of t2.

Onw way to do this is -

```
INSERT INTO t2 (ac1,ac2,ac3, ac4) 
    SELECT 
        STAGING_LOGIN_RECORD_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, 
        'N', 
        'PARTNER', 
        c1 
    FROM t1;
```

but this is taking too much time.

I have almost 10 million records.

is there any effective way to do this? In batches or something?

I am open to other ways like writing procedure or any other ideas.

Comment: Have un indexed your tables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to improve the SQL insert query performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364004/how-to-improve-the-sql-insert-query-performance)

Comment: try a `PARALLEL` hint. [Parallelizing INSERT SELECT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-2627DC19-7EBE-4C45-A758-711BDB5E37EC.htm)

Comment: @JoeTaras Yes, table is indexed.

Comment: What means 'too much time' and why is it too much? What time is acceptable? Is this a unique action or do you have to do this periodically? Should your target table be fully available during this procedure? Do you have to delete the corresponding data in the source table, too? What is the version and edition  of your Oracle database? Is it a production system or a test/dev system? Did you already try the improvements proposed in the link of @JohnHC's comment? Does the target table already contain data?

Comment: @miracle173 - I am looking for other efficient ways that can minimize the execution time with you guys kind help. Target table will be available all the time during the procedure execution. Yes, the target table may contain data. No, the data in source table not to be deleted. It's in dev then will go to test and then prod. Yes I tried those with 40K records difference was in 1-2 secs that also fluctuating, means every new execution was giving new time.

Comment: @miracle173 DB version - Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: what means "without fail" in the title. Did you get any errors?

Comment: @miracle173 "Without fail" means, i used it generically in respect of execution time

Comment: you can start with a 'create table as select' in your test environment, this xcludes the indexes and makes direct load insert. this will be the best you can get on the insert part. then you can try to get this time when you insert into the target table. your statement can be slowed down by fetching the sequence numbers (you can increase the cache size of the sequence) or maybe it helps to create to create an index on c1 if the size of a row of the source table is large compared to c1. you can trace your session or check ash-views to see where performance is lost.

Comment: Try replacing `INSERT` with `INSERT \*+ APPEND *\ `. Also try setting the defaults of ac1, ac2, ac3 to values you are explicitly setting and omitting them from the select. Dropping indexes on t2 before the insert and adding them back again afterwards may also help. If you can live with `NO LOGGING` on your index and/or data tablespace this would also help.